# install vqmod for cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, vqmod

I am trying to install vqmod in cake php framework.
I simply uploaded the vqmod folder to the root and created a controller file with following code and placed the file in **/app/controllers**

```
class VqmodController extends AppController { var $name = 'Vqmod'; }
```

I am getting the following error

```
Missing Database Table
Error: Database table vqmods for model Vqmod was not found.
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\views\errors\missing_table.ctp
```

Friends kindly help me to install vqmod for cake php framework cuz i am unable to find any help via google.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what is vqmod is... but if you have no table for vqmod then this will solve your problem-

```
class VqmodController extends AppController {

 var $name = 'Vqmod';
public $uses = array();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Fazal, now i am Getting a different error
------------------------------
Missing Method in VqmodController

Error: The action install is not defined in controller VqmodController

Error: Create VqmodController::install() in file: app\controllers\vqmod_controller.php.

<?php
class VqmodController extends AppController {

 var $name = 'Vqmod';


 function install() {

 }

}
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\views\errors\missing_action.ctp

Comment: Its showing because you didn't create any action or method name `install` on VqmodController.php...

Comment: Vqmod has a file that installs it, its placed in its folder **/install/ugrsr.class.php**  it has no method defined ... vqmod is easy to use but looks like its not easy to install in any platform other than opencart :(

Comment: Well, Cakephp is very flexible... It will be wise to create a Cakephp plugin with vqmod... This will also helps other to use vqmod with cakephp...

Comment: any clue how to create this plugin?

Comment: Man...I really don't know the function of vqmod... But for plugin development you can take help from Cakephp documentation.. Its well described there.....